# #flutter dart connection to ODBC driver issue

Tags: sql-server, flutter, dart, odbc, database-connection

I am trying to get a working method to connect flutter project with mssql but none of those tries really worked such as (https://github.com/MoacirSchmidt/dart_mssql), I've found a complete ODBC from gitHub (https://github.com/jcmellado/dart-odbc) but it had this error as shown in the picture attached , any one can help me with that ; thanks in advance ^_^
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsuFF.png)

Comment: Please post your error as text not as an image.

Comment: The error message seems to explain it. Have you searched for the same error message affecting other people, such as: [Version solving failed #21421](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21421)